# Inrush Thermistor Bypassing

Tags: power-supply, thermistor, solid-state-devices, inrush-current

Hi I want to bypass an Inrush Limiter Thermistor. It is between the rectifying bridge and the smoothing capacitors, I was considering using a solid state device.

After the rectifer current only flows in one direction, so I considered using a mosfet because I have good quality ones lying around. However, would the charged capacitors maintain a reverse voltage on the mosfet when the AC wave goes down? In such case would a mosfet be unsuitable?

Then my next choice would be an SCR/Triac right?

p.s.: voltage is 12V to 15V AC, 4A max, I have 6600uF of capacitance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rectifier doesn't enforce a decrease in voltage, only that the output is greater than or equal to the input minus a diode drop or two.  Otherwise the caps wouldn't do much except possibly blow up from excessive ripple.

If you leave the FET on, then it's basically a low-value resistor that can pass current in both directions.  Might as well call it a wire unless you're really concerned about it.  To keep it on, you simply need a gate-source voltage that satisfies the threshold.

When the FET is off, it theoretically works like an open switch to both polarities...except for the parasitic diode in parallel that's impossible to get rid of.  So you'll orient the FET so that the diode will block the normal flow of current and choose the channel type to control it conveniently given that orientation and which rail it's on.

Seems to me like it ought to work.  I assume you're going to start with it off, to let the thermistor do its job of limiting inrush, then turn it on and leave it on?

---

Thinking through several configurations in my head, I think you'll be stuck with the gate referenced to the line side of the thermistor instead of the load side, unless you can boost it beyond the normal supply rails.  But if you put a resistor between gate and source to hold it off and then pull it to the opposite supply rail to turn it on, you should be good.  As long as the controlling circuit can handle the full, unfiltered rectifier while the main caps charge.

Comment: Yes your assumption is correct. I was planning on using an N channel FET, drain on rectifier side, source on capacitor side, and driving the gate using a schmitt trigger with an RC filter on the input to create the delay.

Your point is, I'm never going to be able to make Vgs be higher than Rds*current right? So it'll be impossible to turn the mosfet on after the caps are charged..? So I need a P channel device and pull it down after the caps are charged?

Comment: I think you should be able to do this with PMOS (assuming thermistor is on high side). But what is the resistance of the current limiter after the caps charge up? It should be relatively low at that point, I would think. At least I would do a search to see if I could find one that would work before I put a MOSFET in parallel.

You will have to make sure you do not expose the PMOS gate-to-source to the full input voltage, unless you can find one that can handle that and still has a low enough Rds for your application.

Comment: I want to bypass the thermistor in case the circuit gets powered off and on, then the NTC will still be hot and the circuit unprotected.

Comment: In the configuration that you're thinking, either the FET/thermistor are on the high side or the parasitic diode is forward biased, which would limit the thermistor's effectiveness.  So let's say it's on the high side.  An N-FET requires a higher voltage on the gate than on the source, so you'll need to boost it somehow.  Not at all unheard of, but it does add complexity.  A P-FET would allow you to pull it down, but to get the diode oriented right, you'd need to turn it around, hence my original description.

Comment: @Wesley: (rereading your comment) Yes, that's exactly right.  Rds_on should be very low, so you shouldn't get an appreciable voltage drop.  Certainly not enough to drive the gate.

Comment: If you really like N-FET's, you could move the whole works to the low side.  You'd still have the source towards the rectifier and the drain towards the caps, but at least it'd be an N-FET and you could pull it up to the positive supply rail to turn it on.

Comment: So if I already have good quality N-FETs, thats a viable and decent option? Are there any cons? I was checking SCRs/Triacs and the voltage drop/power dissipation would be much, much higher.

Comment: p.s.: and if I build it on the low side, how do I reference two circuits to a common ground?

Comment: The only cons that I can see right now are the work to rearrange an existing circuit, if you already have it, and how to interface with another circuit that isn't powered from here, as you mentioned.  The easiest way is probably to take your common ground from the load side of the FET/thermistor and let the rectifier and transformer secondary do what they will.  If the transformer is isolated like most of them are, and this is all that that winding is driving, then you can do that.  From the other circuit's perspective, the positive rail would appear to move up, just like the P-FET version.

Comment: Do you think you could provide a part number for the thermistor? Also, and correct me if I am wrong, the thermistor provides protection by maintaining a high resistance at certain times, to limit inrush. Bypassing it with a FET can never increase the resistance (since the FET is in parallel). So how does bypassing improve protection under any circumstances? I think there is something I am REALLY not getting.

Comment: In principle, it makes absolutely no difference whether you put the FET on the top or the bottom, except for grounding issues. But to bypass the thermistor, if that is what you want to do, it needs to be on the same side as the thermistor. If you really want to use an NMOS, then put the thermistor and FET on the bottom for ease of turning on the gate. To be continued.

Comment: There is only one thing I will caution you about. If there are any external ground connections, make sure you think them through carefully. If either side of the NMOS is connected to GND, you can create an accidental path through other equipment when the FET is off. For example, if one side is connected to earth ground through power entry and the other side is connected to earth ground through signal exit, then your FET can never be off as it is shorted through earth ground.

Comment: @mkeith: He's using the thermistor as intended for startup (FET off), but noticing that it normally stays hot during operation and takes a while to cool down, thus leaving the circuit unprotected against short glitches.  After startup, the FET turns on and allows the thermistor to cool, so it's ready for a glitch.

Comment: @mkeith: Also, the grounding issue that you mentioned is what prompted my conditions about the transformer being isolated and not driving anything else from that winding.  If that's true, then you can pick any point you want to be ground.

Comment: @AaronD thank-you for the explanation. It makes sense. Once you go to bypass, it might be workable to use a power resistor instead of NTC.

Comment: Hehe, about the power resistor vs the NTC I just wanted to be extra careful, in case the bypassing device fails, the power resistor would heat up and blow up, hence the NTC.. bit of an overkill..

Answer (score 1):

PMOS

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiezT0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

NMOS

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDF0GI.png)</sup>

This might work. R1 is meant to represent the thermistor. The 100k/10uF RC will cause FET to turn on slowly. Diode is supposed to allow FET to turn off quickly. Part numbers are just defaults that came up in circuit lab. Pay them no mind. Diode non-symmetry between the two cases makes me think I screwed up on diode placement in one of the cases. But I am a bit tired and it is not coming to me.

It is very possible that this will be too slow at turning on, causing FET power dissipation. There are a couple of other ideas I am thinking about that might be better. But I though I would put this out there for you to comment on.

Comment: Your N version looks okay.  Mirror that for the P version.  Also, the OP mentioned a schmitt trigger to turn the FET on quickly, so that could solve the power dissipation issue.  Though I might be tempted to use a comparator with lots of hysteresis/positive feedback.

Comment: Because I plan to connect multiple circuits together, I think it'd be safer to use the PChannel version. This psu feeds a power side of a LED driver module which also receives analog dimming voltage from another circuit that is powered from the same winding on the transformer but another rectifier. (Sorry for the mess)